# Citation in captions for Figures or Tables

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, quarto, citations

I am using Quarto and would like to cite in some Figures (or Tables), inserting the citation, for example, using @Foo2020 as my citation key.

Specifically, I want to signal Pandoc within the Figure/Table footnote argument, inside the code chunk in my Quarto.qmd file that there is a citation, like in the regular qmd file.

For example, working on the index.qmd file:

According to @Smith2020 results show: {r} #| label: tbl-tablex #| tbl-cap: Some great insights #| echo: false  foo %>%  flextable() %>%     set_table_properties(layout = "autofit") %>%    add_footer_row(values = "Source: @Smith2020.")

Since I don't want to add it manually, I was wondering if there is a way to cite using Markdown citations so that it could be generated/placed in the bibliography:

```
#| label: fig-mtcars
#| fig-cap: "MPG vs. horsepower, colored by transmission."


library(ggplot2)
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$am <- factor(
    mtcars$am, labels = c('automatic', 'manual')
)
ggplot(mtcars2, as(hp, mpg, color = am)) +
    geom_point() +  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "loess") +
    labs(caption = "Source: Smith2020, et al. 2020")
```

Comment: Which part are you trying to do programmatically? Do you mean you want to put "@Foo2020" in the plot's caption argument and have it expanded? Or you want to signal to Pandoc that you've used Foo et al so the citation is placed in the bibliography it generates? If the former, you might be able to hack something together with `citr`; if the latter, you can [force Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#including-uncited-items-in-the-bibliography) to include items you haven't directly cited

Comment: I want to signal Pandoc within the Figure/Table footnote code chunk in my Quarto.qmd file that there is a citation, like in the regular qmd file. I was not thinking of expanding the plot caption, but that could be a nice feature.

For example, working on the index.qmd file:

According to @Foo2020 results show:

```{r}
#| label: tbl-tablex
#| tbl-cap: Some great insights
#| echo: false

foo %>%
 flextable() %>%
 set_table_properties(layout = "autofit") %>%
 add_footer_row(values = "Source: @Foo2020.")
 
```

More text.

Comment: @NicolásSacco, can you edit your question to include what you have commemted with clearly specifying what you are trying to do? :-) And what is footnote code chunk?